# Quicksort algorithm in vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am having difficulties with the following task. I am able to create a double vector to store the prices of all products and services but I have no knowledge as to how I can associate the name of the product/service to the sorted price list.

Task Description

Use the code developed for HW 2. Implement a function to apply the Quicksort sorting algorithm.

Driver Program:

(1) Modify the classes’ code (if needed) and write a program to sort the collection of Items based on their total price.

(2) After the collection is sorted, use a loop to print the name, department and total price of each element in the Items list.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

/**
    enum globaly declared since both classes will use the same enum values.
    @amount Amount to reduce the price.
    @percentage Percentage to reduce the price.
    vector type string to store the IDs of the departments created.
*/
enum DiscountType { Amount, Percentage };
vector <string> storeIDs;
vector <double> storePrices;

void insertionSort(vector<double>& v) {
    for (int p = 1; p < v.size(); p++) {
        double tmp = v.at(p);
        int j;

        for (j = p; j > 0 && tmp < v.at(j - 1); j--) {
            v.at(j) = v.at(j - 1);
        }
        v.at(j) = tmp;
    }
}

void quicksort(vector<double>& v, int low, int high) {
    if (low + 10 > high) {   
        insertionSort(v);
    }
    else {
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        if (v.at(middle) < v.at(low)) {
            swap(v.at(low), v.at(middle));
        }
        if (v.at(high) < v.at(low)) {
            swap(v.at(low), v.at(high));
        }
        if (v.at(high) < v.at(middle)) {
            swap(v.at(middle), v.at(high));
        }
        double pivot = v.at(middle);
        swap(v.at(middle), v.at(high - 1));
 
        int i, j;
        for (i = low, j = high - 1; ;) {
            while (v.at(++i) < pivot) {}
            while (pivot < v.at(--j)) {}

            if (i < j) {
                swap(v.at(i), v.at(j));
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        swap(v.at(i), v.at(high - 1));
        quicksort(v, low, i - 1);
        quicksort(v, i + 1, high);
    }
}

class Department {
public:
    /**
        Parametered constructor for Departments without a parent.
        @param id The ID of the department.
        @param n The name of the department.
        @param r The room of the department.
        @param pn The phone number of the department.
    */
    Department(string id, string n, int r, string pn) {
        checkID(id);
        dname = n;
        room = r;
        phone_number = pn;
        parent = NULL;
    }
    /**
        Parametered constructor for Departments with a parent.
        @param id The ID of the department.
        @param n The name of the department.
        @param r The room of the department.
        @param pn The phone number of the department.
        @param d The address of the parent department.
    */
    Department(string id, string n, int r, string pn, Department& d) {
        checkID(id);
        dname = n;
        room = r;
        phone_number = pn;
        parent = &d;
    }
    /**
        @return The name of the department.
    */
    string getDName() {
        return dname;
    }
    /**
        Runs a binary search to search if the ID already exists or not in the storeIDs vector. If yes then the user
        is prompted to enter a new one. If not then is stored at the storeIDs vector for future checks.
        @param id The ID of the deparment that needs to be checked.
    */
    void checkID(string id) {
        string tp = id;
        while (binary_search(storeIDs.begin(), storeIDs.end(), tp)) {
            cout << "ID already exists! Please enter a new one to create the department!" << endl;
            cin >> tp;
        }
        ID = tp;
        storeIDs.push_back(ID);
    }
protected:
    string ID;
    string dname;
    int room;
    string phone_number;
    Department* parent;
};

class Item {
public:
    /**
        Declaring getTotalPrice as pure virtual in order to make the class an abstract one.
        Declaring getName function as pure virtual in order to access the name of item and display it
        along side the price.
    */
    virtual void getTotalPrice() = 0;
    virtual string getName() = 0;
};

class Product : public Item {
public:
    /**
        Parametered constructor serving as a super constructor for Service subclass.
        @param n The name of the product.
        @param c The category of the product.
        @param dp The respective address of the department.
    */
    Product(string n, string c, Department& dp) {
        pname = n;
        category = c;
        department = &dp;
    }
    /**
        Parametered constructor for Product class.
        @param n The name of the product.
        @param de The description of the product.
        @param c The category of the product.
        @param p The price of the product.
        @param di The discount made to the product.
        @param dt The type of discount made to the product.
        @param dp The respective address of the department.
    */
    Product(string n, string de, string c, double p, double di, DiscountType dt, Department& dp) {
        pname = n;
        description = de;
        category = c;
        department = &dp;
        setPrice(p);
        setDiscount(di);
        discountType = dt;
        getTotalPrice();
    }
    /**
        Price of the product must not be negative but can be free. Sets the minimal price to 0.
        @param p The price of the product.
    */
    void setPrice(double p) {
        if (p < 0.0) {
            price = 0.0;
        }
        else {
            price = p;
        }
    }
    /**
        Discounts made to the product must not be negative but can be zero. Sets the minimal discount to 0.
        @param di The discount made to the products price.
    */
    void setDiscount(double di) {
        if (di < 0.0) {
            discount = 0.0;
        }
        else {
            discount = di;
        }
    }
    /**
        Returns the name of the respective department that developed the product.
        @return The name of the department.
    */
    string getDepartmentName() {
        return department->getDName();
    }
    /**
        Returns the name of the product or the service as in itself the service comes from the
        superclass Product.
        @return The name of the product.
    */
    string getName() {
        return pname;
    }
    /**
        Returns 0 in case the discount is more than the price of the product, making the product free this
        way. Returns (price - discount) if the discount type is amount or [price - (price * discount / 100)]
        if the discount type is in percentage.
        It is also declared with the same name as the subclass Service so to enable dynamic binding is
        declared virtual.
        @return Total Price = 0.
        @return Total Price = price - discount.
        @return Total Price = price - (price * discount / 100).
    */
    virtual void getTotalPrice() {
        double totalPrice = 0.0;
        if (price < discount) {
            cout << "Discount bigger than price!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            if (discountType == Amount) {
                totalPrice = price - discount;
                storePrices.push_back(totalPrice);
            }
            else {
                totalPrice = price - (price * discount / 100);
                storePrices.push_back(totalPrice);
            }
        }
    }
protected:
    string pname;
    string description;
    string category;
    Department* department;
    double price;
    double discount;
    DiscountType discountType;
};

class Service : public Product {
public:
    /**
        Parameterd constructor for Service subclass followed by its superclass parametered constructor.
        @param n The name of the service.
        @param c The category of the service.
        @param dp The respective address of the department.
        @param du The duration for the service to be completed.
        @param r The rate charged for the service.
        @param rd The discount rate applied to the service.
        @param rdt The discount rate type applied to the service.
    */
    Service(string n, string c, Department& dp, double du, double r, double rd, DiscountType rdt) : Product(n, c, dp) {
        setDuration(du);
        setRate(r);
        setRateDiscount(rd);
        discountType = rdt;
        getTotalPrice();
    }
    /**
        Duration of a service can never be negative nor zero. Setting minimal duration at 1 min.
        @param du The duration of the service to be completed.
    */
    void setDuration(double du) {
        if (du <= 0.0) {
            duration = 0.01;
        }
        else {
            duration = du;
        }
    }
    /**
        Rate of a service must not be negative, but the service can be free. Setting the minimal rate at 0.
        @param r The rate charged for the service.
    */
    void setRate(double r) {
        if (r < 0.0) {
            rate = 0.0;
        }
        else {
            rate = r;
        }
    }
    /**
        Discount rate of a service must not be negative, but it can be zero. Setting the minimal discount rate at 0.
        @param rd The discount rate applied to the service.
    */
    void setRateDiscount(double rd) {
        if (rd < 0.0) {
            rate_discount = 0.0;
        }
        else {
            rate_discount = rd;
        }
    }
    /**
        Returns 0 in case the discount rate is more than the rate of the service, making the service free this
        way. Returns (rate - rate_discount) if the discount type is amount or [rate - (rate * rate_discount / 100)]
        if the discount type is in percentage.
        @return Total Price = 0.
        @return Total Price = rate - rate_discount.
        @return Total Price = rate - (rate * rate_discount / 100).
    */
    void getTotalPrice() {
        double totalPrice = 0.0;
        if (rate < rate_discount) {
            cout << "Rate Discount is bigger than the rate!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            if (ratediscountType == Amount) {
                totalPrice = rate - rate_discount;
                storePrices.push_back(totalPrice);
            }
            else {
                totalPrice = rate - (rate * rate_discount / 100);
                storePrices.push_back(totalPrice);
            }
        }
    }
private:
    double duration;
    double rate;
    double rate_discount;
    DiscountType ratediscountType;
};

// Controls operations of the program.
int main() {
    /**
        Defining vector of pointers of object instances of Department Class.
        Defining vector of pointers of object instances of Item Class
    */
    vector <Department*> departments;
    vector <Item*> items;

    /**
        Creating three instances of Department Class.
        Adding these instances into the vector of pointers called departments.
    */
    Department* d1 = new Department("ABDG-3045", "IT Department", 202, "+355");
    Department* d2 = new Department("VTSB-0075", "Management", 117, "+358");
    Department* d3 = new Department("XHGT-4125", "Operations", 106, "+1", *d2);
    departments.push_back(d1);
    departments.push_back(d2);
    departments.push_back(d3);

    /**
        Creating three artifacts.
        Adding these artifacts into the vector of pointers called items.
    */
    Item* i1 = new Product("O-Class", "Platform implementing online teaching", "Software", 259.99, 40.0, Percentage, *d1);
    Item* i2 = new Product("MngAPP", "Application implementing management fundamentals of a business", "Software", 199.99, 25.00, Amount, *d1);
    Item* i3 = new Product("NixonOp", "Physical workshop explaining fundamentals of operations department", "Workshop", 12.99, 0, Amount, *d3);
    items.push_back(i1);
    items.push_back(i2);
    items.push_back(i3);

    /**
        Creating three services.
        Adding these services into the vector of pointers called items.
    */
    Item* i4 = new Service("Server Maintenance", "IT-Service", *d1, 1.5, 36.99, 15.0, Percentage);
    Item* i5 = new Service("Management Lessons", "Learning", *d2, 2.1, 99.99, 10, Amount);
    Item* i6 = new Service("Cable Management", "IT-Service", *d1, 0.5, 29.99, 0, Amount);
    items.push_back(i4);
    items.push_back(i5);
    items.push_back(i6);

    int n = storePrices.size();
    quicksort(storePrices, 0, n - 1);
    
    cout << "Sorted Total Prices: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << storePrices[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

There is also a problem with the getTotalPrice() function at the Services class. The section below does not execute at all and whenever I have a Service discount in percentage it is applied as an amount and not as a percentage but at the Product class this works totally fine. This is the section that has a problem:

```
void getTotalPrice() {
    double totalPrice = 0.0;
    if (rate < rate_discount) {
        cout << "Rate Discount is bigger than the rate!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        if (ratediscountType == Amount) {
            totalPrice = rate - rate_discount;
            storePrices.push_back(totalPrice);
        }
        else {
            totalPrice = rate - (rate * rate_discount / 100);
            storePrices.push_back(totalPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre] with a focus on the minimal

Comment: Don't do `int p = 1; p < v.size(); p++`. `v.size()` has unsigned type, but `int` is signed.

Comment: *"I am able to create a double vector"* -- what you are able to do and what you should do are not necessarily the same thing. Using two vectors is inadvisbale as it leads to problems when it is time to "associate the name of the product/service to the sorted price list".

Comment: *"write a program to sort the collection of Items"* An `Item` should be represented by a class that has an ID and a price. When you sort the vector of `Item`s, the ID and price will always be together.

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah i though about doing it that way but then I have the problem that this price data field should get the value from the getTotalPrice() function which will throw an unresolved external symbol

Comment: Get rid of `storeIDs` and `storePrices`. What you want is `quicksort(items, 0, items.size()-1);` In other words, *"sort the collection of Items"*

Comment: @HermesÇati An unresolved external symbol is a LOT easier to address than the problems stemming from using a "double vector" instead of a single vector of `Item` classes. Are you sure you want to plow ahead with the harder, more convoluted approach?